# totalWater-runoff graph is showing norhing. Either my If command is not working or I have written codes incorrectly in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have tried to create water-runoff to the farmers with lower elevation from the farmers with highest elevation with excess water (up-down stream water runoff). But my graph for water run-off is displaying nothing. please correct my mistake!

```
 Globals [
      water-req
      elevation
      rain-amount
      total-runoff]
    patches-own [
      ]

    Breed[farmers farmer]
    farmers-own[farms
       ]

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::::: Environment Setup;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    to setup
      ca
      ask patches [
                   set pcolor green ]
                  create-farmers num-farmers
      ask farmers [
                  set rain-amount random monthly-rain
                  set water-req  10 + random 15

                  set elevation  xcor + ycor
                  move-to one-of patches

                  ]

 reset-ticks
 end

to go
   ask farmers [ 
     drain-water
    ]
    chart
    tick
    end

to drain-water
  if rain-amount > water-req ; Global of water-rew is set 
         [ let excess-rain-water rain-amount - water-req
                  let draining-farmers other farmers  in-radius srounding-farms with [elevation  >  [elevation] of myself and excess-rain-water > 0 ]
                   if draining-farmers = nobody [ stop]
                     ask draining-farmers [ set rain-amount rain-amount -  excess-rain-water ]
                       set  rain-amount rain-amount + excess-rain-water
                        set total-runoff  total-runoff + excess-rain-water


]

end



to chart

  set-current-plot "water runoff"
  plot total-runoff
  set total-runoff  0


end
```

[chart setting for water-runoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj6Fh.png)

Comment: Things look ok in this code, but there is a chance that the plot is setup incorrectly in your GUI. 

Can you post a screen capture of your plot settings?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I  am getting no option to edit my question to post a screenshot.

Comment: I have added link above for graph settings. @AndrewYoak  please see.

Answer (score 1):

I think your trouble comes from using both **reset-ticks / ticks** as well as a the **set-current-plot / plot** commands. **Tick** actually automatically performs the **update-plots** action. Here is more info: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#plotting

I understand that you want to reset total-runoff each day back to 0 and then add to it, so you can fix this by either adding:

[set-current-plot-pen](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set-current-plot-pen) "default"

before plot total-runoff in your code, or you can just take out:

```
 set-current-plot "water runoff"
  plot total-runoff
```

and add:

```
plot total-runoff
```

to the **pen update commands** sections for the first pen in your plot.

Either way should do it.

Comment: I have followed your suggestions, graph is not showing up nothing again.